# How to collapse and expand program icons in the notification area?

Tags: 22.04, xubuntu, system-tray

How can I collapse and expand program icons in the notification area / system tray?

I can hide icons on xubuntu/xfce with "Status Notifier Plugin", but I'm looking for a expand menu function like in Windows.

If xfce doesn't have something like that, I'm also interested in whether there is another desktop in Ubuntu with this function.

Comment: I don't know about XFCE, but I know KDE has it. Configure system tray > Entries > Application status > Visibility > "Shown when relevant" -> "Always hidden", then find it in the "^" icon in the taskbar

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I would recommend xfce or gnome, but if there is no other option I would try kde.